# Почему запрос SQL выполняется с ошибкой?

Tags: mysql

```
$sql = "ALTER TABLE `users`
DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS `gender`";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Колонка gender удалена <br>";
} else {
    echo "Ошибка $sql " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

То есть я хочу удалить поле gender, если оно существует.

Но выбрасывает такую ошибку: Ошибка ALTER TABLE `users` DROP COLUMN IF EXISTS `gender` You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IF EXISTS `gender`' at line 2

Comment: https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=10789. Можно процедуру создать и в ней проверять наличие колонки и дропать если существует, но проще забить и дропать без проверки

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/173814/using-alter-to-drop-a-column-if-it-exists-in-mysql

Comment: [ALTER TABLE statement](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html) - покажите, где Вы там нашли IF EXISTS для DROP COLUMN... PS. Если требуется выполнять DDL из клиентского кода, то есть серьёзные погрешности в архитектуре.